# How far we have to consider the plug-ability while designing an email service using external library

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, email

I was designing an email service in `.net standard 2.0` using [`mailkit`](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) library. I proposed the following design
[image: my proposed design]
This design was not accepted stating the following reasons:

1. This design have to many components. Basically it adds more LoC.
2. It proposes interface for models.
3. If anyone want to implement Imap, then its increases the complexity.

Based on these comments, another design was proposed and accepted as follows:

[image: Accepted design]

For me 1st design is better because:

1. Its more plug-able while the 2nd design is structured towards `mailkit` library
2. Its more easy to unit test, while 2nd one required reading through mailkit library to find implementations of `mailtransport` and `ImailService`
3. `mailkit`already provides `smtpclient` and `imapclient`. We can make use of that instead of going through library and find both implementations inherits from `mailtransport`/`IMailService`
4. More readable code and the responsibilities are defined correctly.

Are those valid points?. If not what are the flaws in 1st design?
While designing a service how far we have to consider plug-ability?

Comment: 1.  Is "It's more plug-able" a *specific requirement* of the software you are writing?

Comment: 2.  What does "scraping through mailkit library to find implementations" mean?

Comment: 3.  Your point 3 seems to support the second design.

Comment: 4.  I would dispute your point 4.  Adding additional layers of indirection does not automatically confer better readability or division of responsibilities.  There is a cost to all those interfaces; if a technique doesn't pay for itself in significant benefits ...

Comment: Plugability is not a requirement but as per my understanding when we design we have to make system as independent as possible so that in future instead of mailkit some other library can be easily integrated. @RobertHarvey

Comment: Well, it either is a requirement or it isn't.  If it isn't, [you don't need it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

Comment: Regarding point 3: 2nd design uses mailtransport where it is found by code reading the library. While in library documentations it gives how to use smtpclient which inherits from mailtransport. 1st design uses smtpclient

Comment: Are you really designing an e-mail service or more a front-end to the library you found? Nothing wrong with that if you do, but you will be fairly constrained by what the  library can do, and you don't want to over-engineer some exensibiliry mechanism that's never needed.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to implement email service for your already existing application.

Your application don't need to care about smtp or other email protocols, what it should care is just abstraction of a service which will be responsible of sending email out.

```
public interface IEmailService
{
    Task SendEmailAsync(EmailMessage message);
}
```

`IEmailService` and `EmailMessage` is only "email" dependencies your application should care about.

Then you can create implementation in the project which will depend on application's `IEmailService` and `EmailMessage`

```
// Another project
public class SmtpEmailService : IEmailService
{
    private readonly SmtpConfiguration configuration;

    public SmtpEmailService(SmtpConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public async Task SendEmailAsync(EmailMessage message)
    {
        var client = CreateClient(configuration);
        var message = new
        {
            To = message.To,
            Subject = message.Subject,
            Body = message.Body, 
        };

        await client.Send(message);
   }

    //...CreateClient
}
```

`SmtpConfiguration` is an implementation detail and will be injected to the Smtp project at the entry point of your application (composition root).

With the approach above, business logic will have minimal dependencies on email implementation details and any implementation of `IEmailService` can be replaced(plugged) with other implementations only by registering different implementation in composition root.